# Which materials abosrbs heat? And which are good in practical applications

Tags: thermoelectricity

I want to design a component which cools the water in the absence of ice cubes,fridge etc.. Like water heater which works by electric supply.. Similarly water cooler which is independent of electricity. So the material we are using to cool the water should absorb heat as well as it has to transform it to electric form (which is given to battery).

See this picture to get a clarity of my idea:
$\hspace{100px}$[image].

Comment: So you basically want a heater that works in reverse - this is, instead of using electricity to create heat, it draws in heat to create electricity?

Answer (score 0):

This is the ["party boat" concept](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/399463/the-sun-is-giving-us-a-low-entropy-not-energy/399471#399471). It's impossible to implement with just the water, the device, and the battery because you'd have to destroy entropy (which is forbidden by the Second Law) when you try to turn the thermal energy into an equal amount of electrical energy.

However, you *could* use a [thermoelectric generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator) between your water and a colder reservoir elsewhere. In this case, the entropy would be transferred to the cold reservoir, and the limit of cooling for your water container would be (in the best scenario) the temperature of the cold reservoir.

Answer (score -2):

i **think**  this is similar to the idea of the tesla coil

your idea would be extremely good if possible

another way of stating this question so it is a bit more clear-

how is it possible to take all heat(movement of an atom) transform this kenetic energy to move one electron

electrons are so light compared to an atom so the possibility of this would be similer to a train traveling so fast and colliding with a feather

sadly in real life this dosnt happen that feather is connected to another train with the strong force

to answer you i think so not possible HOWEVER check this out

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator

device that takes the movement of heat and makes electricity from that (this is not exactly what your talking about but similar)it is not directly making electricity from heat but instead the transfer of heat